# How can I connect to an unthreaded galvanized pipe stub for a garden hose?

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe

I've got a galvanized pipe in my garage that is used for a garden hose. It's fairly rusty. The end has been cut off so there are no threads left - I need a way to attach something to this pipe so I can put on an elbow and convert it to a garden hose.

A few things:

- The pipe runs under a concrete pad so it's not possible to replace it without a major expense
- The water doesn't need to be drinkable
- Aside from the surface rust, the walls of the pipe are still very much intact

So, I tried using a rubber connector, which almost worked, but I can' clamp it down tight enough to make a 100% seal. I am going to try sanding the pipe next which might solve this, but I don't imagine this rubber connector would last long outside.

Any ideas? Can I re-thread this pipe? Is there some sort of sharkbite I can connect to unthreaded Galvanized? Compression fitting? [image]

Comment: I would clean up the pipe as good as I could with sandpaper, coat the pipe with RTV silicone, slide the rubber connector on as far as I could and add a second clamp close to the first clamp and tighten both with a socket wrench for more torque. let stand for a couple days before using.

Comment: Answers go down there. :)

Comment: Are you willing to get a little janky with the solution? I'm not saying you *should* do things that aren't normally approved, but...

Comment: If you're considering non-DIY solutions brazing a threaded fitting on may be a possibility. (Depending on the size of the hole/skill of the welder) Heating the zinc on galvanized pipe requires a respirator so it's hardly the kind of thing you want to tool up for yourself. It's likely cheaper than tearing up everything though.

Comment: that rubber adapter will blow out use a galvenized commpression coupling to connect the new galvenized pipe to the old pipe.

Answer (score 3):

Buy a Ratcheting Pipe Threader with 1/2" steel die, or whatever size pipe that is, and thread the pipe. $35 at Harbor Freight or $80 at Northern Tool. Sand and use thread sealant as needed.

Answer (score 2):

They make fittings that we call "Moody Couplings"; this may be a regional or colloquial term but probably evolved from a manufacturer's name.

[image]

These **are** designed for pressure pipe, the size designed for 1/2" galvanized pipe also fits 3/4" copper. These are *not* designed to be installed in locations where a leak would not be evident/fixable, and they do require a relatively smooth outside surface (but are a bit forgiving in that respect). If you do this, I recommend *not* covering it up, so you can monitor.

Comment: The hose clamp coupler that you have used, depicted in your picture, is *not* designed for pressure applications.